How do i set the timezone with Chart.js and date-fns adapter?
I am using Chart.js v4.4.2 with the date-fns adapter v3.0.0.
I've managed to customize the format of the time scale to a 24-hour clock by putting the following customization on the scales.x object:
    time: {
        unit: "hour",
        displayFormats: {
            hour: "HH:mm",
        },
    },

However, the times are shown in my local timezone. How can I get it to show UTC?
There's no mention of timezone in the Axes configuration

I am trying to do this too. I need everything in UTC. Let me know if you figure it out.

I want to offer you to use time.parser option instead of modifying the data:
time: {
    unit: "hour",
    displayFormats: {
      hour: "HH:mm"
    }
  },
  parser: (value: Date) => {
    return new Date(
      value.getUTCFullYear(),
      value.getUTCMonth(),
      value.getUTCDate(),
      value.getUTCHours(),
      value.getUTCMinutes(),
      value.getUTCSeconds()
    );
  }
}

Or use Date.UTC in the code above.

The best I have come up with is to modify the data before giving it to chartjs.
var ConvertToFakeUTC = function(originalData)
{
  var diff = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
  var result = Array.from(originalData, (e) => ({x:e.x+diff, y:e.y}));
  return result;
};

I say 'Fake' because adding the timezone offset actually results in a WRONG date that prints UTC using the local timezone. I don't love it, but it works. The getTimezoneOffset() function returns minutes, so I convert that to milliseconds as all my x values are a millisecond timestamp. I have not tried luxon yet but it is supposed to be a cleaner solution, especially if you want timezones other than UTC or local time.
